# WordPress Multisite with subdomains on different domains

Tags: multisite, subdomains, domain-mapping, network-admin

I want to create a WordPress Multisite network with domain mapping.
In my project, we need 10 sites in the network. Every site uses a subdoman on differnt domains.

Fo example:

- blog.apple.com
- news.facebook.com
- social.twitter.com

Is there any chance to do that with the multisite feature?
I've only found solutions with different subdomains on a single domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to assign the appropriate subdomains using 301 redirections? I think it would be possible if you run all these websites on one server.

1. Create multisite with subdomains in one domain
2. Assign custom subdomains directories to paths of your network installations.

As far as I know, it is pretty simple in CPanel and difficult but possible in DA.